# React Native Not Supporting the font 'Neusa'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts

I am developing an React native app and I am using some custom fonts in the app. I successfully imported installed liked the fonts and it is working fine. But one font name neusa not working(Not showing). When font is called it loading only default font. i am sure all custom fonts i am using is .ttf. All other fonts i downloaded from google fonts but not this one. can any one please suggest a way to fix it

The [link](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e) i followed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are 100% that you followed the guide to the letter then the problem might be that you are using the wrong fontFamily. Not all fonts have the font family equalto their names. This happens a lot with FontAwesome.

Upload your font here: http://torinak.com/font/lsfont.html

It should tell you the fontFamily that you need to use. Otherwise you could log the font names that RN is detecting but that involves a little more work